# When teaching a beginner AngularJs, what do you think is the simplest smallest AngularJs 'Hello World' example

Tags: angularjs

What is the Simplest 'Hello World' in AngularJS for a beginner. So far I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-app="">
        {{'Hello World' }}
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use dynamic angular binding by create a controller. [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Comment: what will that teach anyone? Doesn't show anything with regard to 2 way data binding. scope or directives. Anyone learning angular needs a bit of javascript background already. You can learn jQuery without much javascript background, not angular.

Comment: egghead.io tutorials start at a good level, IMHO, check them out for inspiration:  http://egghead.io/

Comment: Hi charlietfl, what do you think about this: It depends on who is using it. Angular js in the hands of a core JavaScript developer provides him data binding, DI, etc in which you need JavaScript background to learn to do all that. But again, angular in the hands of a designer could be about simply extending the html by just applying directives and filters etc, which is one of the goals of the developers of angular('sprinkling some html magic'). in any case both are using angular.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest Hello World that shows 2-way databinding

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <title> Hello World </title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>{{helloWorld}}</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="helloWorld"></input>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function MainCtrl($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = "Hello World";
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**:
A bit of explanation on what is what and why this is (in my view) a minimal Hello World app showcasing the power of AngularJS

1. The AngularJS library needs to be included
2. The custom attribute *ng-app* is added to kick of the angular application. This directive signals AngularJS to auto-bootstrap an application
3. The *ng-controller* directive is added and it's associated javascript function shows exposing an object by assigning it to the injected $scope
4. The double brackets expression *{{helloWorld}}* shows the convention used by AngularJS to output model values.
5. The *ng-model* directive is used to bind the helloWorld object and shows the power of AngularJS two-way datababinding

Comment: I'd +1 this if the controller was named `MainCtrl` and not `mainCtrl`. It's a constructor function, after all. Also, better code formatting and some comments to show whats' going on...

Answer (score 2):

Simplest AngularJS 'Hello World' - "The Good Way"

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head> 
        <!-- .... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
            <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script>

            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

            myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
                $scope.name = "World";
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found on prettycode.org:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title> Hello World </title>
</head>
<body>
    Your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
    <p ng-show="name">Hi, {{ name }}!</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```